# Is there a way to control height of a drop down list select?

Tags: html, user-interface, html-select

I have a popup div that my product manager wants me to place a drop down select box. the problem is that the drop down, when opened, overlaps the popup window's boarder. (See below awful ascii art)

```
____________
|My Popup  |
|  ____    |
| |___V|   |
| |    |   |
|_|    |___|
  |____|
```

As you can see, my product manager wants me to limit the size that the dropdown select's expands so that it does not exist the popup.

Everywhere I have searched, everyone has said this is not possible. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using the `size` attribute?

Comment: Would it be allowable to adjust the height of the pop-up so it can accommodate the pop-up?

Comment: adding size attribute changes the drop down control to render the box as a listbox instead

Comment: @ChrisHardie is there a way to determine how tall the list box items will appear? it seems like the number of items is relative to the size of my browser window is at the time of clicking the down arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If popup positioned absolutely, there is no html/css way to do this. But javascript can help ya with this, just add offset top + height of you sub-popup to height of main popup.

Comment: I am not sure I am following... I only have one popup, which is absolute positioned in the middle of the screen, then all of the controls in that popup are posistioned relative within said div. (also, for other reasons the contents is in an iframe, please don;t judge me for that, other control limitations unfortunately)

Comment: I'm sure there is some way you are using to call those elements , something like :hover, so you just need to add a resize function that will trigger on hover and resize your container and resize it back on mouseout

Answer (score 1):

This should help you out. very elegant and clean.

http://css-tricks.com/long-dropdowns-solution/

Comment: unfortunately, this does not meet our UI guide lines. thanks for the post though!

Comment: @NathanTregillus that's a shame. How about setting a suitable line-height to each list item of your drop down menu?

Comment: I thought about that too, but based upon the context you open the popup, the dropdown could have 5 items, or it could have 99 items (max)

Comment: Obvious, but have you tried setting the height of 'li' selector? A radical option would be to limit the number of items of the dropdown. But I guess that would be too limiting for you.

Comment: at this point I was hoping for some quick and dirty solution, but it looks like the number of displayed items in the list is controlled by the browser, and there is no way to specify to the engine that I only want 5 elements at a time in the list, rather than 25.

Comment: sure, I'll try to get an example put together tonight

Comment: Hi @NathanTregillus, did you have any joy?

Comment: Sorry Dura, here is my jsfiddle, just listing the type of issue i have
http://jsfiddle.net/Medrio/EQgDN/